# Image field getting empty in the data base while updating the other fields

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I am uploading multiple images into the folder and name into the database. I tested and it's working.

Now my issue is, I am on the edit page and  I haven't change the image and I updated the input field value and Saved it. My input field is updated but my slider field getting empty.

The below code I am using for my file type and img for preview image and hidden input field for storing the image name in the value

```
<div class="row">
   <?php 
    $sliders=explode(",", $companyInfo['slider']);
    foreach ($sliders as $key => $h) {?>
         <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 mb-3">
            <div class="upload_doc">
               <input type="file" name="slider[]"  class="fileupload noofslider">
               <div class="uploadInfo">
                  <div class="upload_icon"></div>
               </div>
          <div class="previewImage"></div>
  <div class="afteruploadedImage uploadedCompany"> <img  src="assets/images/uploads/sliders/<?php echo $h;?>" alt="" class="singlePreview" />
  <input type="hidden" name="slider[]" value="<?php echo $h;?>"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <?php } ?>
      </div>

<input type="text" name="name"> <!--I am updating this field-->
```

**This is logic part**

```
/*Multiple slider*/
$gallery_images = $_FILES['slider'];
$file_post = $_FILES['slider'];
$gallery_images=[];
if($file_post['name'][0]!=''){
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
         $location='assets/images/uploads/sliders/';
        if(!$r_value =resizeImage($file_ary[$i], $location, 800)){
            $status = 0;
        }else{
            $gallery_images[] = $r_value;
        }

    }
}

// echo "<pre>";
//  print_r($gallery_images);

 $allsliders = implode(",",$gallery_images); // if I upload images then it's displaying my image but if I add the name input and this is showing empty.
```

Comment: You can check if input image is empty don't update the row of image in db

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, Yes, I am little bit confused in the logic. Do I need to add like this if (isset($_POST['slider'][$i]) && $_POST['slider'][$i]!= "") { }

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, any more help in this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if image input is fill or not then choise if update with mysql or not.

I prefer use `isset` with `is_file` for check if exist
Example:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file_post'][0]) && is_file($_FILES['file_post']['tmp_name'][0])) {
    //do some stuff
}
if (!empty($gallery_images)) {
    $allsliders = implode(",", $gallery_images);
    $sql = "UPDATE company SET slider=:slider,name=:name WHERE company_id=:company_id";
    $data = array('slider' => $allsliders, 'name' => $_POST['name'], 'company_id' => 1);
} else {
    $allsliders = implode(",", $gallery_images);
    $sql = "UPDATE company SET name=:name WHERE company_id=:company_id";
    $data = array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'company_id' => 1);
}
```

Then choise if update your query with image or not.

Comment: Change `if($file_post['name'][0]!=''){` with mine and put `query` for update image into that `if` and second `query` for update if exist others data.

Comment: I tried but it's still clear the records and now I am not able to add the image after adding your answer

Comment: post yout query too

Comment: i am using update query. $sql="UPDATE `company` SET `slider`=:slider,`name`=:name WHERE  `company_id`=:company_id";

Comment: $data=array(
              'slider'=>$allsliders,
              'name'=>$_POST['name'],
              'company_id'=>1
          );

Comment: i add a simple `if` for check if array is empty or not and choise which query execute.